Why do OnKeydown and OnClick work differently in my code?
I am creating a Dino game where jumping is triggered by either clicking (anywhere) or pressing space.
I added a last phase (4) where the same keys will still trigger the same function jump(), but then jump() will do something different in phase 4 (there will be something like hitting a boss).
When I use clicks, my code works as intended, but when I use spaces, in the last phase 4, jump() does not perform as intended: it does update isJumping I see the animation I put work, but it doesn't update the other state variables: craMessage and craLife.
Why don't Onclick and Onkeypress function the same in this case? What did I do wrong in my code?
Thank you in advance.
// src/App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Dino from "./components/Dino";
import Obstacle from "./components/Obstacle";
import Ground from "./components/Ground";

const App = () => {
  const [isJumping, setIsJumping] = useState(false);
  const [obstaclePosition, setObstaclePosition] = useState(1000);
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [scoreMessage, setScoreMessage] = useState("");
  const [phase, setPhase] = useState(1);
  const [lastPhase, setLastPhase] = useState(1);
  const [craLife, setCraLife] = useState(1000);
  const [craMessage, setCraMessage] = useState("");
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState(false);

  // Handle jump (both keyboard and mouse)
  const jump = () => {
    if (!isJumping) {
      setIsJumping(true);
      setTimeout(() => setIsJumping(false), 500); // Dino stays in the air for 300ms
      if (phase === 4) {
        //used same variable isJumping for hitting logic
        let hit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 150 + 200); //Boss in phase 4 will be hit between 200 and 350
        setCraMessage(`-${hit}`);
        setCraLife(craLife - hit);
        setTimeout(() => setCraMessage(""), 1000);
      }
    }
  };

  // Function to handle phase changes and difficulty scaling
  const adjustPhase = (score) => {
    if (score >= 10) {
      if (lastPhase !== 4) {
        // Show message only if phase changes
        setPhase(4); // Phase 4: New game components
        setScoreMessage("Phase 4: New Challenges!"); // Show message for Phase 4
        setTimeout(() => setScoreMessage(""), 1000); // Remove message after 1 second
        setLastPhase(4); // Update lastPhase
      }
    } else if (score >= 4) {
      if (lastPhase !== 3) {
        // Show message only if phase changes
        setPhase(3); // Phase 3: Increase speed & randomize obstacle interval
        setScoreMessage("Phase 3: Speeding Up & More Obstacles!"); // Show message for Phase 3
        setTimeout(() => setScoreMessage(""), 1000); // Remove message after 1 second
        setLastPhase(3); // Update lastPhase
      }
    } else if (score >= 2) {
      if (lastPhase !== 2) {
        // Show message only if phase changes
        setPhase(2); // Phase 2: Increase speed
        setScoreMessage("Phase 2: Speed Boost!"); // Show message for Phase 2
        setTimeout(() => setScoreMessage(""), 1000); // Remove message after 1 second
        setLastPhase(2); // Update lastPhase
      }
    } else {
      if (lastPhase !== 1) {
        // Show message only if phase changes
        setPhase(1); // Phase 1: Initial state
        setScoreMessage("Phase 1: Get Ready!"); // Show message for Phase 1
        setTimeout(() => setScoreMessage(""), 1000); // Remove message after 1 second
        setLastPhase(1); // Update lastPhase
      }
    }
  };

  // Move obstacle with changing intervals based on phase
  useEffect(() => {
    if (gameOver || phase === 4) return;

    const baseInterval = 50; // Base interval (500ms for phase 1)
    const speedIncreasePerPhase = 10; // Increase speed per phase (reduce interval by 100ms)
    let interval = baseInterval - (phase - 1) * speedIncreasePerPhase; // Decrease interval as phase increases

    const updateObstaclePosition = () => {
      setObstaclePosition((prev) => {
        if (prev <= -50) {
          setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
          if (phase === 3) {
            return Math.random() * 500 + 500; // Randomize position between 800 and 1500
          }
          // In other phases, keep the position fixed
          return 1000;
        }
        return prev - 10;
      });
    };

    const intervalId = setInterval(updateObstaclePosition, interval);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [gameOver, phase]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (gameOver || phase !== 4 || craLife <= 0) return;
    setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 10);
  }, [gameOver, phase, craLife]);

  useEffect(() => {
    adjustPhase(score); // Update phase based on score
  }, [score]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ensure craLife doesn't go below 0
    if (craLife <= 0) {
      setCraLife(0); // Stop craLife from going negative
      setScoreMessage("You win!");
      setTimeout(() => setGameOver(true), 1000);
      return;
    }

    if (obstaclePosition < 60 && obstaclePosition > 10 && !isJumping) {
      if (phase === 4) {
        if (craLife <= 0) {
          setScoreMessage("You win!"); // If craLife is 0 or less, show win message
          setGameOver(true); // End the game
          return;
        }
      }
      setGameOver(true); // Game ends in other phases regardless of craLife
    }
  }, [obstaclePosition, isJumping, phase, craLife]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
      console.log("Keydown triggered:", e.key);
      if (e.key === " ") {
        jump();
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        height: "300px",
        width: "100%",
        overflow: "hidden",
        background: "#ddd",
      }}
      onClick={jump} // Allow mouse clicks to trigger jumping
    >
      {gameOver ? (
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Game Over! Score: {score}</h1>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Dino phase={phase} isJumping={isJumping} />
          <Obstacle
            phase={phase}
            position={obstaclePosition}
            isLifted={isJumping}
          />
          <Ground />
          <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: "10px", left: "10px" }}>
            Score: {score}
          </div>
          <div> Message: {scoreMessage} </div>

          {phase === 4 && (
            <>
              <div> Cra Life: {craLife} </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: "50px",
                  right: "80px",
                  color: "red",
                }}
              >
                {craMessage}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


This is a large amount of code for people to read and understand, and most of it has nothing to do with event handling, at least not directly. Maybe work up a test case so that there is less "noise" to ignore.

As a general comment, adding and removing event handlers is, to me, a bad way of managing event handling rules and logic. It's much better to leave the event handlers installed essentially at page init time and leave them there, and then use your own code in the handler, with its own appropriate state management, to decide if and how to do its thing.

Add dependecies in keydown


useEffect(() => {
  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === " ") {
      jump();
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
}, [jump, isJumping, phase, craLife]); // Add dependencies



